# How to do inline shell replace alongside other formatting options like cut and pipe

Tags: linux, string, bash

I am trying to do the following:

Start with a variable containing a space separated list of parameters - $cmd_str (contains about 6 parameters), lets say it looks like:

```
cmd p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6
```

My goal is to try to print them:

```
Params:
   1 - p1
   2 - p2
   etc...
```

so the first I have to cut off the "cmd" string and then I was going to replace spaces with "\n\t[n] - ", where n is the number

So far I have:

```
echo $cmd_str | cut -c5-
```

Then I wanted to add string replacement, but could not get it to work

```
echo ${$cmd_str | cut -c5-// /"\n\tnum - "}
```

Then I was going to have to replace each occurance of "num" with the number in a loop... but I have not got that far! - might be a retarded way doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using BASH arrays:

```
cmd_str="cmd p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6"
arr=($cmd_str)
for ((i=1; i<${#arr[@]}; i++)); do printf "%d - %s\n" $i "${arr[$i]}"; done
1 - p1
2 - p2
3 - p3
4 - p4
5 - p5
6 - p6
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk -v RS=' ' 'NR>1{printf "%d - %s\n", NR-1, $1}' <<< "$cmd_str"
1 - p1
2 - p2
3 - p3
4 - p4
5 - p5
6 - p6
```

Comment: ridiculous...........ly easy!, well at least the first solution is. I totally don't understand the syntax of the second solution - it's beyond me : ), what even does "<<<" do? - thanks very much.

Comment: `<<<` is called here-string which is used to feed some string as input to some command. `-v RS=' '` sets input record separator as space for `awk`. But yes my preference is also for first solution.

Comment: Thanks anubhava, I like that <<< may come in really handy!

Comment: @code_fodder : `<<<` is about redirecting to std in, so you could also write that code as `echo "$cmd_str" | awk ....` Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

If `cmd` is your script, use the special parameter `@` which expands the positional parameters.

Ex:

```
let i=0
echo "Params:"
for p in "${@}"; do
    let i+=1
    printf "\t${i} - %s\n" $p
done
```

Comment: Its not parameters passed in to my function, but that looks like it would work, I can extract the printf and loop and probably use that